# Why does solubility of $\rm NaCl$ increases with increase in temperature?

Tags: temperature

If the volume of water decreases with increase in temperature then why does solubility of $\rm NaCl$ increases with increase in temperature…i mean to say that if the volume increases then the solubility increases but in this case just opposite is happening so i want to know the reason behind it?

Comment: At most temperatures, the mass density of water _decreases_ with increasing temperature -- the reverse is only not the case for water around its freezing point.  Could you _edit your question_ for clarity, especially the starting temperature?

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: You are mistaken. The volume of liquid water increases with increasing temperature. Only at the phase change between liquid and solid does it undergo an expansion.

Comment: You picked a bad example: **the solubility of sodium chloride in water increases very little with temperature over the range from 0 Celsius to 100 Celsius!**

Answer (score 4):

The higher the temperature, the faster the salt ions rattle around in solution. This makes them less likely to re-stick themselves onto the surface of a piece of solid salt sitting in the water, and thereby biases the (solid salt) - (dissolved ions) equilibrium towards (dissolved ions) and away from (solid salt).

Comment: Worth noting that this is a general rule with solids, they become more soluble in liquid solvents with higher temperatures

Answer (score 2):

Solubility of the most of the salt rises with increase in temperature. This is because with increase in temperature, kinetic energy of the molecules increases and the solvent molecules break apart the solute molecules that are held together by intermolecular attractions more effectively.